# Response isn't a type, cannot and expected to find ';'

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to send a post request within dart with the following code.

```
Future<Response> post (url,
        {
        headers,  // My Map<String, String> for header info
        body      // My Map<String, String> for body info
        })
    return JSON.jsonDecode(post);
```

I expect it to send, however, I get two errors.
`The name response isn't a type, and cant be used as a type argument`, when I hover over "Response" and
`expected to find ;`, when I hover over "post".
I also get green underlining in android studio saying `avoid unnecessary statements`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens in Computers with low specs which makes android studio take time to recognize new input. Waiting will fix the issue, and you can speed this "recognition" process by clicking on the type `Response` in you case which will make the editor focus on it. And also add parenthesis and commas in correct way before adding new code as `Dart Analyzer` will quickly get confused and fill your editor with error messages.

Comment: The dart analyzer was confused. Relaunching android studio fixed the problem. Wasn't a low spec issue. Was running off a a brand new expensive mac at the time. This will help others though

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, and I found that rerunning `flutter pub get` helped as that command makes sure the Http library gets downloaded.